# Proving linearity of solutions to nonhomogeneous linear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm pretty new to ODE's I'm not sure If I can prove the linearity of solutions to a general nonhomogeneous linear ODE.

I started off with:

$a_0(t)x + a_1(t)x' + \ldots + a_n(t)x^{(n)} = b(t)$ from the wiki

Assume $a_0, a_1 \ldots, a_n$ and $b$ are functions of $t$

Rearranging a bit for $a_0(t)x$

$a_1(t)x' + \ldots + a_n(t)x^{(n)} - b(t) = -a_0(t)x$

Now lets assume that there are $k$ unique solutions to this system: $x_1, x_2 \ldots x_k$

What I'm trying to prove is that $z = c_1x_1 + c_2x_2 + \ldots + c_kx_k$ is then also a solution to the system for $c_1, c_2, \ldots c_k \in \mathbb{R}$

Next I substitute $x(t) = z(t)$ on the RHS of the rearranged equation.

$-a_0(t)z = -a_0(t)(c_1x_1 + c_2x_2 + \ldots + c_kx_k)$

$= c_1(-a_0(t)x_1) + c_2(-a_0(t)x_2) + \ldots + c_k(-a_0(t)x_k)$

Then substituting back the rearranged equation I get

$= c_1(a_1(t)x_1' + \ldots + a_n(t)x_1^{(n)} - b(t))$

$+ c_2(a_1(t)x_2' + \ldots + a_n(t)x_2^{(n)} - b(t))$

$+ \ldots +$

$+ c_k(a_1(t)x_k' + \ldots + a_n(t)x_k^{(n)} - b(t))$

The rest is just some simple rearranging to arrive at:

$a_0(t)z + a_1(t)z' + \ldots + a_n(t)z^{(n)} - b(t)(c_1 + c_2 + \ldots + c_k)$

But really this is where my problems arise. I don't really see a way of getting rid of the sum term at the end unless I additionally restrict them to sum to 1. Am I missing something here?

I know that this shouldn't be an issue for homogeneous systems because the b term would just be 0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't missing anything. Your equation is of the form $(Lx)(t) = b(t)$, or $Lx = b$ for short, where $L$ is a linear operation. So if you have solutions $x, y$ with $Lx = b$ and $Ly = c$, then $L(x + y) = b + c$. The space of solutions to $Lx = b$ is an affine subspace: Let $x_0$ be any particular solution to $Lx_0 = b$. Then $$\{x : Lx = b\} = \{x_0 + y : Ly = 0\}.$$